# Parse error in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that will yield average cost per disease. I'm sure this isn't the best method, but it does seem to work when I feed it a column index. However, when I wrap it in a function and execute the code, I get a parse error:

```
    Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:2: unexpected '=='
1:  ==
     ^
```

Here is some sample data:

```
t <- data.frame(Asthma = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                Diabetes = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                CF = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                AnnualSpend = c(12345, 23323, 50000, 10000, 543))
```

Here's my for loop:

```
y <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:ncol(t)-1) {

  n <- names(t[i])

  s <- paste(n, " == 1", sep="")    

  r <- t %>% filter_( s ) %>%
             summarize( Avg = mean(AnnualSpend) )

  x <- cbind(n,r)

  y = rbind(x,y)

}
```

I did step through it with 1 as the column index, then use parse(text = s), which seemed to work just fine. I'm just a little confused why it works when I do it manually, but it fails as a function. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I run exactly what's above, I do get the error. Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes, and the problem does not reproduce. Did you try to open the fresh R session and copypaste EXACTLY what is in your post.  Don't type anything else.

Comment: If you type one character which is not in your post, the problem is not reproducible.  You can ONLY copypaste, not touch the keyboard.

Comment: I just did, and I get the same error. Your last comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: What part of my last comment you don't understand?

Comment: My message was "Error: I cannot find a function '%>%'"

Comment: They are suggesting you need to add `library(dplyr)` to your code. @user31264, it would be helpful to just come out and say that instead of a 7 comment back-and-forth to get that.

Comment: "If you type one character which is not in your post, the problem is not reproducible" - strictly speaking, this means there is a character that solves the problem. I tried what you said - new R session, copy/paste code, and I get the same error.

Comment: I have dplyr loaded.

Comment: rwking: *you* may have it loaded, but *we* don't (unless you tell us that it is necessary).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans - makes sense that I should have added the necessary packages. Would have been helpful and a time saver if user31264 could have simply stated that fact. :)

Comment: Just to clarify what the commentors are saying, when posting your code, it is good practice to also indicate all the libraries needed to execute your code, to make us aware of what we need to load to execute and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll walk you through finding where your code is broken.

You get the error in the `filter_` line, so check what filter you are actually trying to apply:

```
s
# [1] " == 1"
```

Of course this is wrong. Why would it be this way? You should check out the code that generates it. What's wrong with it?

```
n
# character(0)
```

Huh, that doesn't make sense either, `n` should be one of the names of the `data.frame`. Okay, let's keep tracing back:

```
names(t)
# [1] "Asthma"      "Diabetes"    "CF"          "AnnualSpend"
names(t)[i]
# character(0)
```

Okay, so it must be `i`:

```
i
# [1] 0
```

In R, indexes are 1-based, not 0-based, but you probably knew that. However, the reason it is 0 is that you specified `1:ncol(t)-1`. Based on the order of operations, that's effectively `(1:ncol(t)) - 1`, though I suspect you intended `1:(ncol(t)-1)`.

```
1:ncol(t) - 1
# [1] 0 1 2 3
1:(ncol(t) - 1)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

When you change that code, your results:

```
y
#          n     Avg
# 1       CF 12345.0
# 2 Diabetes 31172.5
# 3   Asthma 24622.0
```

It's important to know not just "what code language does what", but it's also important to be able to step through the code (forwards or backwards) to find where a symptom turns into a problem-source.

Comment: Thanks for this. This explains why I could run it with an integer, but not run it as a loop. The problem was in my loop syntax. Really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Please accept one of the two offered answers; it's polite to us, and it provides closure to the question in case anybody else finds it.

Comment: Man, give a guy a minute.

Comment: you are a fast typer :) should you or I provide the more efficient way to do this than a for loop, or just link to the many previous examples...

Answer (score 1):

When debugging code, print the output at each step.  For instance, I print(i) and I find that no value is returned, indicating the function does not even make it to this step, meaning the problem is upstream.

Since the only value upstream is a for statement, check what is in the for statement:

```
1:ncol(t)-1
# [1] 0 1 2 3
```

Read the statement, you are asking for a seq 1:ncol(t) and subracting 1 from the sequence.  Therefore i is starting at zero and is incorrect.  You are missing () around (ncol(t)-1).  Below is the corrected code.

```
for(i in 1:(ncol(t)-1)) {
  n <- names(t[i])
  s <- paste(n, " == 1", sep="")    
  r <- t %>% filter_( s ) %>%
    summarize( Avg = mean(AnnualSpend) )
  x <- cbind(n,r)
  y = rbind(x,y)
}
```

A for loop is not the most efficient way to do this though.

Comment: Beat you by *four seconds* :-)

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the help. I figured it wasn't the best way, but I'm pretty new to R and still learning.